# Know what the error is, but I can't figure out how to solve it

Tags: c#

Here's my code:

```
mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Columns["SysID"]);
```

Here's my error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataColumn' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

I'm trying to get the value of the column "SysID" and convert it to an integer.  The compiler thinks, though, that I'm trying to convert the actual column, not the value.  For the life of me, I can't figure this out.  I know I'm missing something obvious, I even tried adding a `.value` (example: `Columns["SysID"].value;`) but that isn't it.  Can someone show me what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I've added my entire program below, for clarity.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace CopyExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\MaintList.xlsx", "C:\\Import");
            var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", fileName);
            var db = new ModulesDataContext();
            var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [AM IST$]", connectionString);
            var ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelData");

            DataTable ExcelData = ds.Tables["ExcelData"];

            foreach (DataRow row in ExcelData.Rows)
            {
                Module mod = new Module();

                mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Columns["SysID"]);
                mod.Module1 = ExcelData.Columns["Num"].ToString();
                mod.Title = ExcelData.Columns["Title"].ToString();

                db.Modules.InsertOnSubmit(mod);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another Edit:

Okay, I tried changing the line giving me problems to this:

```
mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[row]["SysID"]);
```

However, the editor puts a squiggle line under it and I get an error message when I try to run the program:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataRowCollection.this[int]' has some invalid arguments

Made the following changes to the code and it now works perfectly:

```
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in ExcelData.Rows)
        {
            Module mod = new Module();

            mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[counter]["SysID"]);
            mod.Module1 = ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Num"].ToString();
            mod.Title = ExcelData.Rows[counter]["Title"].ToString();
            mod.Type = "ICW";

            db.Modules.InsertOnSubmit(mod);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Is ExcelData a DataTable? It's hard to answer this question fully without knowing how the indexing operator of ExcelData.Columns works.

Comment: Columns don't have values.  Each row has a value at each column.

Comment: You should read rows, not columns, I guess.

Comment: Try to convert the bound item

Comment: As others are alluding to, if `ExcelData` is the table, then do:  `ExcelData.Rows[0]["SysID"]` to get the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to access values from the columns. In .NET, as well as most other frameworks, when you have a table structure, you access values from the rows first, then the columns, not from the columns directly.

I don't know the exact property you should use because I have never used that API, but I'm quite sure it should be something like:

```
mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[foo]["SysID"]);
```

**Edit:** So ExcelData is a `DataTable`. Therefore the code above should be right. For DataRow collections, the first indexer is the actual row index, and the second one is for the column. I had thought it was some other class from some Office API.

Comment: I actually tried doing this before, using row instead of foo.  The editor gives me an error message (noted in my post above).

Comment: I figured out that I can't use my row variable but I can use a counter variable, and just increment it while looping through and use that for my row counter (i.e. mod.SystemID = Convert.ToInt32(ExcelData.Rows[counter]["SysID"]) )  Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: The parameter inside the first brackets must be an integer. But well, you figured that out.